# OWASP Tricks to speed up vulnerabilities checks

Tags: maven, owasp

I use the maven project with the OWASP plugin to check the vulnerabilities on each commit in the CI pull requests.
The configuration looks pretty simple

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.dependency-check-maven}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>aggregate</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <showSummary>true</showSummary>
                            <!-- this will work only in the top-level maven module -->
                            <suppressionFile>${user.dir}/owasp-suppressions.xml</suppressionFile>
                            <format>ALL</format>
                            <failBuildOnAnyVulnerability>true</failBuildOnAnyVulnerability>
                            <!-- alternative: fail on level (High starts at 7, Critical at 9) -->
                            <!-- <failBuildOnCVSS>4</failBuildOnCVSS> -->
                            <assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>false</assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>
                            <cveUrlModified>address of the NVD local mirror</cveUrlModified>
                            <cveUrlBase>address of the NVD local mirror</cveUrlBase>
                            <cveWaitTime>1</cveWaitTime> <!--value in milliseconds, default is 4000-->
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

For CI builds I use PROW - https://docs.prow.k8s.io/docs/overview/
For local mirror approach is described here https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/data/mirrornvd.html and the mirror is used from here https://github.com/stevespringett/nist-data-mirror/

Still the process to download CVEs from mirror takes quite a lot of time (around 3 minutes). From the logs I can see the most of time is spent on downloading CVEs

```
[INFO] Download Started for NVD CVE - 2003
[INFO] Download Complete for NVD CVE - 2003  (5 ms)
[INFO] Processing Started for NVD CVE - 2003
[INFO] Processing Complete for NVD CVE - 2002  (4608 ms)
[INFO] Processing Complete for NVD CVE - 2003  (1131 ms)
...
```

and for doing some DB maintenance?

```
[INFO] Begin database maintenance
[INFO] Updated the CPE ecosystem on 128773 NVD records
[INFO] Removed the CPE ecosystem on 3604 NVD records
[INFO] End database maintenance (13482 ms)
[INFO] Begin database defrag
[INFO] End database defrag (3765 ms)
[INFO] Check for updates complete (112132 ms)
```

Do you know any tricks to speed up OWASP checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was replied on this other thread: [How to cache OWASP dependecy check NVD database on CI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75002846/10606656)

Basically you need to tell PROW to cache the location of the NVD database which when using the Maven plugin is:

`$MAVEN_HOME/.m2/repository/org/owasp/dependency-check-data/7.0/nvdcache/`

** Considering that you use Dependency-Check version 7.+

Comment: Nice, unfortunately I moved to another company and can't validate it, but as well there are no other answers I will accept this one.