# How to cache OWASP dependecy check NVD database on CI

Tags: caching, continuous-integration, owasp, devsecops

OWASP dependency check it's a great way of automating vulnerability discovery in our projects, though when running it as part of a CI pipeline per project it adds 3-4 minutes just to download the NVD database.

How can we cache this DB when running it with maven / gradle on a CI pipeline?

Answer (score 6):

After a bit of research I found the way!

Basically, the files containing the NVM db are called: `nvdcve-1.1-[YYYY].json.gz` i.e. `nvdcve-1.1-2022.json.gz` which are later added to a Lucene index.

When running Dependency-Check with the Gradle plugin the files are created on:

`$GRADLE_USER_HOME/.gradle/dependency-check-data/7.0/nvdcache/`

When running it with Maven they are created on:

`$MAVEN_HOME/.m2/repository/org/owasp/dependency-check-data/7.0/nvdcache/`

So to cache this the DB on Gitlab CI you just have to add the following to your `.gitlab-ci.yaml` (Gradle):

```
before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

cache:
  key: "$CI_PROJECT_NAME"
  paths:
    - .gradle/dependency-check-data
```

The first CI job run will create the cache and the consecutive (from same or different pipelines) will fetch it!

Comment: In case you run Dependency-Check as standalone app, the files should be created in: `[JAR]/data/7.0/nvdcache/` where [JAR] it's the location of the dependency-check-core JAR file.

Comment: Note that NVD has deprecated their "traditional" data feeds, and should remove them soon: https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/data-feeds

They still offer an API, though.